# Comos validar si hay errores al insertar datos en store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda, tengo un aplicativo en c# , que lee un excel y sube la información, 
manda un tabla al store procedure.
Hago un insert haciendo select

```
insert into tabla
select * from @table
```

ha estado funcionando bien pero me gustaria  agrega saber que si hay un error, me diga el error, para yo poder borrar los datos insertados y que me salga un mensaje de error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza esta base de SP. Espero que te sirva.

```
USE [YourDataBase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Stp_NameSP]
    @cVar               varchar(1)      = ''


AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @nError     INT
DECLARE @vchDescripcion VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @cNom VARCHAR(100)

ErrorProc:
    IF @nError <> 0 
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @vchDescripcion = description 
            FROM    master..sysmessages 
            WHERE   error = @nError

            SELECT -1                   Codigo,
                    @nError * -1        CodigoSql, 
                    @vchDescripcion     Descripcion
            RETURN -1
        END

        /*CÓDIGO SQL (CRUD) SEGÚN NECESIDAD*/
    IF @nError <> 0    
        GOTO ErrorProc
    ELSE
        SELECT  @nIdConcepto            Codigo,
                0                       CodigoSql, 
                'Registro oK'   Descripcion
RETURN 0
```